LSFR polynomial next term example
I’m struggling with the mathematical representation of an LFSR as polynomials, and I’d like to understand where I go wrong.
In my example, I use an LFSR with a 5-bit shift to the left and feedback on bits $b_4$ and $b_2$.
My LFSR polynomial is:
$$
P(x) = x^4 + x^2 + 1
$$
Starting with the initial state $(b_4, b_3, b_2, b_1, b_0) = (0, 1, 1, 0, 0)$, we can represent this state as:
$$
S_0(x) = x^3 + x^2
$$
To find $S_1(x)$, I calculated $S_1(x) = (x \cdot S_0(x)) \bmod P(x)$:
$$
S_1(x) = (x^4 + x^3) \bmod P(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1
$$
This gives me the sequence $(0, 1, 1, 1, 0)$, but I was expecting the sequence $(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)$.
Could someone explain my mistake, please?
I also looked at this answer, which discusses getting the output sequence from the characteristic polynomial. However, I’m confused because, in that example, it seems that $S_1 = x^3$ and then $S_2 = x^3 + 1$, which doesn’t appear to involve a shift.


@MaartenBodewes Thanks for the editing I take notes for next post :-)
